# Excel combination of of values to return a specific value in a separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to play around with Excel, and came across this issue.

```
    A       B        C
1  red    blue    purple
2  black  white   grey
3  red    white   pink
```

I want to return a specific string value in column C for each combination of values in column A and B. For example, if I have red for column A and blue for column B, I want to make my formula so that it returns "purple".

Does anyone have a clue what my formula would look like to achieve this?
I'm thinking of using an IF statement, but not sure how to go from there.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank for that self edit, so much clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C1 place the following:

```
=IF(AND(A1="red",B1="blue"),"Purple","not the combination I was looking for")
```

[IF Statement](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) and [AND logical operator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) are your friends here.

Comment: @Minami - kindly see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).